# Filtering "Product review" if the exist in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

My code works fine, but I want to know if there is an easy and faster way to filter it?

I'm doing: "If `current_user` already has a review, do not let him review and hide form".

products_helper.rb:

```
def current_user_commented?
    @product.product_reviews.each do |p|
        current_user.profile.product_reviews.each do |r|
            return false if r == p
        end
    end
end
```

show.html.rb:

```
<% if logged_in? %>
  <% if current_user_commented? %>
    <%= form_for ([@product, ProductReview.new]) do |f| %>
      <div id="star-reviewing"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :comment %>
          <%= f.text_field :body %>
      </div>
      <%= f.submit 'add Comment' %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Not sure if `profile.product_review` is a typo, it's probably the plural form. You haven't posted a lot of code so this might not work, but try something like this: `current_user.profile.product_reviews.where(product: @product).exists?`

Comment: Ouch, its supposed tobe `profile.product_reviews`.
Sorry for less code, didnt put routes/associations. Reviews `Many and/to belongs`. Profile `has_and_belongs_to_many`

Comment: Thanks, its worked: `<% unless current_user.profile.product_reviews.where(product: @product).exists? %>`

Comment: You're welcome! I've added it as an answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
current_user.profile.product_reviews.where(product: @product).exists?
```

This returns `true` if the user has already reviewed `@product`.

This solution is quite efficient as it executes a single database query rather than fetching records and performing equality checks in Ruby.

Also read the Rails documentation on [`exists?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-exists-3F) and [ActiveRecord queries](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html).

Comment: *WHY* should the OP use this? Providing code is nice, but explaining why the code works is very important as it teaches how to reuse it. It's akin to giving someone a fish or teaching them how to fish.

Comment: I've added fishing instructions :)

Comment: Excellent. Thank you. :-)